# LegacyCookieProcessor in standalone Tomcat and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, cookies, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6. I am trying to apply the solution given at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-tomcat-legacycookieprocessor to have "legacy" cookie handling in Tomcat. 
Other than shown in the given URL, I am not using an embedded Tomcat, but a standalone one (5.12.5).

Alas the Bean seems to have no effect at all, although I believe to have done all the necessary things. The IllegalArgumentException is still thrown.

Am I missing something here? How would that HowTo work with a standalone Tomcat? Is it Spring Boot causing my trouble?

Thanks in advance!